# Ascii Table Construction in the Console given a 2-D array

Tags: java

I am wording on a coding assignment for CSCI 161 at North Dakota State University. I am confused on how the formatting commands work for `System.out.Format`. I am given a 2-D array of Integers to apply in the ASCII table and designed headers.

I tried looking online on how each of these work.

```
public class AsciiTable {

 private static int[] getMaxWidths(int[][] data)
 {
        String[] headers = {"|" + "\t" + "Values" + "\t" + "|", "\t" +   "Total Collisions" + "\t", "|" + "\t" + "Max Collisions" + "\t" + "|"};
        int[] maxWidths = new int[headers.length];
        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < data[r].length; c++)
            {
                if (c == data[r].length - 1 || c == 0)
                {
                    if (r == 0)
                    {
                        maxWidths[c] = Math.max(headers[c].length(), ("|" + "\t" + data[r][c] + "\t" + "|").length());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        maxWidths[c] = Math.max(maxWidths[c], ("|" + "\t" + data[r][c] + "\t" + "|").length());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (r == 0)
                    {
                        maxWidths[c] = Math.max(headers[c].length(), ("\t" + data[r][c] + "\t").length());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        maxWidths[c] = Math.max(maxWidths[c], ("\t" + data[r][c] + "\t").length());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return maxWidths;
    }

    private static String getSeperator(int[][] data)
    {
        int[] colMaxWidths = getMaxWidths(data);
        String seperator = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < colMaxWidths.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < colMaxWidths[i]; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0 || j == colMaxWidths[i] - 1)
                {
                    seperator += "+";
                }
                else
                {
                    seperator += "-";
                }
            }
        }
        return seperator;
    }

    public static void printTable(int[][] data)
    {
        int[] maxWidths = getMaxWidths(data);
        int length = 0;
        for (int width : maxWidths)
        {
            length += width;
        }
        String seperatorLine = getSeperator(data);
        System.out.format(seperatorLine + "%\n");
        System.out.format("|" + "%\t" + "Values" + "%\t" + "|" + "%\t" + "Total Collisions" + "%\t" + "|" + "%\t" + "Max Collisions" + "%\t" + "|" + "%\n");
        System.out.format(seperatorLine + "%\n");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so Im asuming here its using String.format as a base : 
define a string where every variable you want to put in is represeneted by : %s for a string %d for a number (for more youll have to look it up I dont know them all https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) : `"the values is %s"` and then add the values in the correct order to the method call :

```
System.out.format("the values is %s",value)
```

or if you have more

```
System.out.format("the values is %s and the other one is %s",value,otherValue)
```

and so on